# Reading and writing to different files on the same time - can multithreading be useful?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, c++11

I'm reading text form a huge file, line by line, perform some operations on them and then store results in different files. If I will have two thread, one that read the data from one file, will other thread be able simultaneously write data to another file? Or as they are o the same hard disk multithreading won't make sense as they will wait for each other?

Comment: If you have a SSD it can be very useful. If not it will depend on several factors.

Comment: Please provide some details of your target OS and architecture including disk technology (HDD, SSD, SAN, RAID) etc. You should expect the platform to try and minimise this kind of contention pretty hard but if you're writing to a single spindle of platters with a single write head buffering and cleverness can only mitigate things so far. It may make sense to increase the buffer size in C++. In theory you could right size buffers to reduce contention between the reader and writer(s). Read, work, read interleaving Work, Write, Work.

Comment: @Persixty I want it to be cross-platform, so not using anything OS-specific or hardware-specific. Just some general code, but the the most efficient as possible

Comment: Then the answer is "It depends on the specifics of your hardware platform". I'd say that you should consider buffering because in principle that should help mitigate the workload but if the process is lopsided between read and process and write you may still get data backing up in buffers. You may need multiple readers/writers/processors to get throughput on some platforms. Wanting a platform independent solution doesn't mean there is one because platforms vary.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you have the three steps

- read
- process
- write

Of course, the hard disk can't perform a read and write operation at the exact same time. However, it could support this:

- read A (HD)
- read B (HD), process A (CPU)
- write A (HD), process B (CPU)
- read C (HD)
- write B (HD), process C (CPU)
- ...

In short, while processing, your program is CPU-bound and the HD is idle. While writing, it is HD-bound (or IO-bound) and the CPU is idle. Interleaving these things can improve overall throughput.

Comment: Don't forget modern computers cache I/O pretty heavily.

Comment: Thanks! I also though in that direction. Also if you don't mind one more question, as I don't really know how many parts of data will the program has and how many thread I'm able to create, I can start process as std::async, so the system will decide if it can create thread or not. With using std::async there can't be possible slowdown of the program, correct?